# How do I best protect Nuxt API endpoints (Supabase db)?

Tags: nuxt.js, prisma, supabase, nuxt3

I'm using Prisma with Nuxt to communicate with Supabase db. Not using RLS, as the recommended way with Prisma seems to be protecting routes on the server side instead. My question is if the below is an efficient way to do it, before I implement for all routes (especially if I really need to do a roundtrip to db every time I will do delete/edit of any record to get the record and see what user it belongs to):

```
//in endpoint for deleting db record
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
import { serverSupabaseUser } from "#supabase/server";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
let user = null;

//check if user logged in, throw Error if not
  try {
    user = await serverSupabaseUser(event);
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("Unauthorized - no user logged in");
  }

//get the id of the record to delete from context params
  const { recordId } = event.context.params;

  //check if this user is the owner of the record to delete
  const record = await prisma.myTable.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: parseInt(recordId),
    },
  });

  if (record.user_id !== user.id) {
    throw new Error("Unauthorized user");
  } else {
    return prisma.myTable.delete({
      where: {
        id: parseInt(recordId),
      },
    });
  }
});
```

This seems to work. But want to make sure I'm not missing something here.

Comment: Any ideas on this? :)